# Buddha's Teachings on Life's Purpose and Existence

Tags: the-buddha, daily-life, existence

I have been ruminating about some existential questions...."what is purpose of life"...."is there a creator"..."what is the best work for a mortal to undertake in their lifetime"...."is suffering from unnecessary burden of study or job justified if they are not bringing satisfaction but are necessary for social survival"... etc, etc.
In what sutta(s) has Blessed One talked about this matters? what solution Master gave to get out of this vicious cycle (referring to the vicious cycle of "ruminating about some existential questions.")which drains the energy?

Comment: It would be good to clarify your last question as there is ambiguity right now. What is the referent when you say "this vicious cycle?" It is possible you are referring to the vicious cycle of "ruminating about some existential questions." On the other hand, it is possible you are referring to something else by "this vicious cycle which drains the energy" such as "daily-life" which you tagged in your question. The two are not necessarily referring the same.

Comment: Ask a Monk: Is there a purpose in life?

https://youtu.be/Vs7MsSPSrdI?si=3WAykwXhl8kysBT_

Answer (score 1):

This question is most excellent in its clarity & lack of ambiguity.

The Buddha's Teachings say Life's Purpose and Existence  is to perform good deeds.

For example, [Dhammapada 53](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/dhp/dhp.04.budd.html) says:

> As from a great heap of flowers many garlands can be made, even so should many good deeds be done by one born a mortal.

The Pali word literally translated as 'mortal' above is 'macca', meaning 'subject to death'.

If good deeds are not done, what *follows from* (*upapajjati*) this waste of life is hell.

[image]

About not purposelessly wasting life, the Buddha said:

> Faith and ethical conduct are kinds of wealth,
>
> Saddhādhanaṁ sīladhanaṁ,
>
> as are conscience and prudence,
>
> hirī ottappiyaṁ dhanaṁ;
>
> learning and generosity,
>
> Sutadhanañca cāgo ca,
>
> and wisdom is the seventh kind of wealth.
>
> paññā ve sattamaṁ dhanaṁ.
>
> When a woman or man
>
> Yassa ete dhanā atthi,
>
> has these kinds of wealth,
>
> itthiyā purisassa vā;
>
> they’re said to be prosperous,
>
> Adaliddoti taṁ āhu,
>
> **their life is not in vain [not wasted]**.
>
> **amoghaṁ tassa jīvitaṁ**.
>
> So let the wise devote themselves
>
> Tasmā saddhañca sīlañca,
>
> to faith, ethical behavior,
>
> pasādaṁ dhammadassanaṁ;
>
> confidence, and insight into the teaching,
>
> Anuyuñjetha medhāvī,
>
> remembering the instructions of the Buddhas.”
>
> saraṁ buddhāna sāsanan”ti.
>
> [AN 7.6](https://suttacentral.net/an7.6/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=sidenotes&highlight=false&script=latin)

Answer (score 0):

Listen as I am going to provide an answer which is woven by my own mind taking threads from here and there (from Buddha and Krishnamurti). But I found a solace into it. I am by no way a Blessed One,but there is a possibility(though scarce) of it happening in future, so till that auspicious day occur there is a need to be ready for it.
Below are three great questions which are asked in question.

- What is purpose/meaning of life ?
- Do I need to Suffer for survival?
- Best way to live?

This questions are called 'Existential Questions',they are like a fire, if controlled then can result into creation else can be fatal. Nitzche died of it!

The Sabbasava Sutta (Majjhima Nikaya 2[11]) also mentions 16 questions which are seen as "unwise reflection" and lead to attachment to views relating to a self.

> Whoever speculates about these things would go mad & experience vexation -acintita sutta

> Vaccha, [any of these views] is a thicket of views, a wilderness of views, a contortion of views, a writhing of views, a fetter of views. It is accompanied by suffering, distress, despair, & fever, and it does not lead to disenchantment, dispassion, cessation; to calm, direct knowledge, full Awakening, Unbinding -Aggi-Vacchagotta Sutta

> Therefore, o monks, do not brood over [any of these views] Such brooding, O monks, is senseless, has nothing to do with genuine pure conduct (s. ādibrahmacariyaka-sīla), does not lead to aversion, detachment, extinction, nor to peace, to full comprehension, enlightenment and Nibbāna, etc. - samyutta sutta

But these should not be taken as permit to suppress this questions else they will catch you when you least expect them and break havoc. Better understand that Purpose or meaning is creation of mind,life is reality. Flowers don't have purpose nor do mountains yet they are alive and do exist in peace. Life has no purpose nor meaning but has beauty, why not experience it?

This is called philosophy of Existential Nihilism. But accepting that life as whole is pointless brings great suffering hence Buddha straight away avoided talking on it,( But it was due to Compassion as I think ) for me I think it's perfectly ok to embrace 'Absurdism'.

Suffering is avoidable to some extent. In cognitive psychology it is well received that addictions are outcomes of brain creating pleasure hormones when receiving certain sensations. All suffering is result of attachment or Karma.

> At Savatthī. “Bhikkhus, I will teach you the origin and the passing away of suffering. Listen to that and attend closely, I will speak.”
> “Yes, venerable sir,” the bhikkhus replied. The Blessed One said this:
> “And what, bhikkhus, is the origin of suffering? In dependence on the eye and forms, eye-consciousness arises. The meeting of the three is contact. With contact as condition, feeling comes to be; with feeling as condition, craving. This is the origin of suffering.

> “In dependence on the ear and sounds … In dependence on the nose and odours … In dependence on the tongue and tastes … In dependence on the body and tactile objects … In dependence on the mind and mental phenomena, mind-consciousness arises. The meeting of the three is contact. With contact as condition, feeling comes to be; with feeling as condition, craving. This is the origin of suffering.
> “And what, bhikkhus, is the passing away of suffering? In dependence on the eye and forms, eye-consciousness arises. The meeting of the three is contact. With contact as condition, feeling comes to be; with feeling as condition, craving. But with the remainderless fading away and cessation of that same craving comes cessation of clinging; with the cessation of clinging, cessation of existence; with the cessation of existence, cessation of birth; with the cessation of birth, aging-and-death, sorrow, lamentation, pain, displeasure, and despair cease. Such is the cessation of this whole mass of suffering. This is the passing away of suffering.
> “In dependence on the ear and sounds … In dependence on the mind and mental phenomena, mind-consciousness arises. The meeting of the three is contact. With contact as condition, feeling comes to be; with feeling as condition, craving. But with the remainderless fading away and cessation of that same craving comes cessation of clinging … cessation of existence … cessation of birth; with the cessation of birth, aging-and-death, sorrow, lamentation, pain, displeasure, and despair cease. Such is the cessation of this whole mass of suffering. This is the passing away of suffering.”
> -Dukkha Sutta

The best way to live is embrace life fully, but with no attachment and meditation. The Noble Eightfold path should be followed but not by taking second hand meanings of original pali terms, I realise that each one should act independently without accepting any authority, hence what is 'samyak' for you should be found out by you yourself.

At last everyone should find his own light, teachings of Masters like Buddha and Krishnamurti are just fingers pointing towards Truth you have to walk by yourself to reach there.

> “Truth is a pathless land. Man cannot come to it through any organization, through any creed, through any dogma, priest or ritual, not through any philosophical knowledge or psychological technique. He has to find it through the mirror of relationship, through the understanding of the contents of his own mind, through observation and not through intellectual analysis or introspective dissection…” - J Krishnamurti.

Comment: Why are you answering your own question? Seeded questions are not allowed according to the sites rules: https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1572/13375

Comment: See here again: https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1785/13375

That is one of the moderators for this site and was written many years ago. Since then we've routinely had this abused and it has caused many problems.

Comment: @YesheTenley I am not interested in argument, if it's not acceptable by community they will take decision and I don't care about it, I did what I thought was good! And this site had feature for it!

Comment: As a moderator I can confirm we don't welcome *certain kinds* of self-answered questions, particularly when the user posts a question with the sole purpose of posting an answer. Asking a genuine question and answering it at a later time if happened to find an answer elsewhere is allowed.